# How do I add multiple rows across multiple columns to get final result based on unique id?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
----------------------------------------
name | type | month1 | month2 | month3
----------------------------------------
abc  | demo1 | 34    | 45     | 54
abc  | demo2 | 45    | 54     | 36
abc  | demo1 |  67   | 40     | 30
```

And I want a answer like but I can't seem to find the query to figure out the total across multiple rows and multiple columns.

```
name | type  | total
-------------------
abc  | demo1 | 270
abc  | demo2 | 135
```

I tried using SELECT name, type, (month1 + month2+ month3) as Total from 'some table' group by type;

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name, type, (SUM(month1)+SUM(month2)+SUM(month3)....+SUM(monthn)) AS Total
 FROM your_table
 GROUP BY name, type
```

Comment: You'll need to `group by` both `name` and `type`.

Comment: Also, `SUM(month1+month2+month3) AS Total` _might_ be faster since the rdbms won't have to maintain multiple running sums.